# I can't implement marzipano tour 360 on local

Tags: javascript, laravel, web, virtual-tour

I'm trying to use Laravel and Marzipano to make my own virtual tour but I'm having trouble making the photos look on the page. The page goes blank and when I click, the mouse changes to the typical 360 photo motion cross. I have no idea where the problem is because it's the first time I've used it and I've never used anything like it.
This is my code:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Trial</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url('js/marzipano/marzipano.js') }}"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="domID"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var panoElement = document.getElementById("domID");
        var opts = {
            controls: {
                mouseViewMode: "drag"
            }
        }

        var viewer = new Marzipano.Viewer(panoElement, opts);

        var levels = [
            { tileSize: 512, size: 512 },
            { tileSize: 512, size: 1024 }
        ];

        var geometry = new Marzipano.CubeGeometry(levels);
        var source = Marzipano.ImageUrlSource.fromString("imgs/R0010598.JPG");
        var view = new Marzipano.RectilinearView();

        var scene = viewer.createScene({
            source: source,
            geometry: geometry,
            view: view
        });

        scene.switchTo();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

run this on LocalHost . try to have some time saving extensions on VS code like LiveServer . Go to Html page and click on GoLive on Bottom Right corner of your screen .Add marzipano.js in project and require it .